# Quickperf @ExpectUpdate does not recognise configured batch size of Jooq

Tags: sql, unit-testing, jdbc, jooq, spring-jdbc

I am replacing the usage of JDBC Template with [Jooq](https://www.jooq.org). For example, to batch update entities in a database. Against this I am running unit tests that use [Quickperf annotations](https://github.com/quick-perf/quickperf), as `@ExpectUpdate`.

The `batch size` in Jooq configuration is set to 100. Now, if I update 650 entities, I would expect 7 queries (650/100) to be executed. However, Quickperf tells me:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: a performance-related property is not respected

[PERF] Expected number of UPDATE statements <7> but is <1>.
```

while batch size seems to be 650 according to Quickperf:

```
[JDBC QUERY EXECUTION (executeQuery, executeBatch, ...)]

    Time:42, Success:True, Type:Prepared, Batch:True, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:650, Query:["update...
```

With JDBC Template, this test would pass with `@ExpectUpdate(7)`.

To update the records, I used Jooq method
`dslContext.batchUpdate( updatableRecords ).execute()`. Then I tried with following Jooq method

```
dslContext.batched( c -> entities.forEach( entity -> c.dsl()
            .update( table )
            .set( table.tableFieldToUpdate, newValue )
            .where( table.tableField.eq( someValue ) )
            .execute() ) );
```

For the latter, the test passes, so batch size seems to be equal to 100 from Quickperf point of view.

Is this, by any chance, a bug in the Quickperf or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Settings.batchSize` flag was introduced in jOOQ 3.14 with [#3419](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3419), only for the `BatchedConnection`. The assumption being that with a `BatchedConnection`, it s hard to otherwise control the batch size, whereas with explicit `batchUpdate()` calls, you can just chunk your `List` and run a nested loop.

But it could indeed be convenient to either extend the flag's reach to other batch usage, or to add additional flags for those other batch API. I've created a feature request for this: [#14840](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14840)